# Convert HTML page to PDF with CSS3 Support

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, pdf

I'm working on a small project whereby I create multiple CVs (or resumes) via an interface I've built in Vue + Laravel, which I can then export to PDF.

I'm having issues though when I export the PDF. Laravel DOMPDF doesn't let me have CSS3 properties inside the PDF, for example flex, or CSS variables. I believe PDFs only support CSS 2.0, but I have seen multiple PDFs being exported that are an exact carbon-copy of the website. For example, [resume.io](https://resume.io) - when you create a CV via their site, they can export it and make it look exactly like the website version.

My question is: does anyone know of a library that I could use that ties into Vue or Laravel that will produce a carbon-copy of the website template into a PDF?

I have tried a few JS libraries that take screenshots of certain elements on the page, then try and fit them together, but it just doesn't work. I basically need a specific element on the page to be selectable and then saved to a PDF. Please see my example below:

[image]

As you can see, the white area is the CV preview, so I need that whole section saved to a PDF, minus the right hand side menu and the top-bar. I'm planning on building some really cool templates, but if I can't use modern CSS practices then it's going to be quite hard to make them into a PDF.

At the moment, I've got two views, the CV preview which you can see above, then another view which re-uses partials that are inserted in the PDF template. Obviously though, reusing the partials which have modern CSS applied then makes the PDF break or look broken.

My stack:

- Laravel
- Vue.js
- TailwindCSS
- Laravel-DOMPDF

If anyone could advise on the best way to go about this, I'd really appreciate it.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't mentioned the converted page is in Vue or Blade, I'll explain both way.

Here's the [Library](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf), which all you need is to design a Blade view, then do something like this

```
Route::get('/doc', function () {
//
    $data = Marketers::all();

    // LoadView with $data
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',$data)->setPaper('A4');

    // LoadView with Compact
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf',compact('data'))->setPaper('A4');

    // Then Download it
    return $pdf->download('pdf.pdf');
});
```

Now in Vue you need [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) and [htmlToCanvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) or [htmlToIMage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image)

i used `HTMLtoImage` because i had some character issues for persian language so I'll help you base on `HtmlToImage` Library.

```
 <template>
        // Part you want to Convert to pdf or ...
        <div  ref="contentz" id="jsPdf" >
        // Contents
        <div/>
 </template>

downloadFull(t) {
    let self = this
    switch (t) {
        case 1:
            const doc = new jsPDF("l", "mm", "a4");
                htmlToImage.toCanvas(document.getElementById('jsPdf'))
                    .then(function (canvas) {

                        var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                        var width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
                        var height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
                        doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, width, 0);
                        doc.save('app.pdf');


                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        self.$notifications.failedNotificationOnGetData(self)
                    });
            break;
        case 2:
                htmlToImage.toJpeg(document.getElementById('jsPdf'), { quality: 1 })
                    .then(function (dataUrl) {
                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.download = 'kalabala.jpeg';
                        link.href = dataUrl;
                        link.click();
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        self.$notifications.failedNotificationOnGetData(self)
                    });
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
}
```

So here's my function which `downloadFull(t)` t will be the file type, you might don't need it or you can improve it with simple if/else without switch, first you you will import libraries like :

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import htmlToImage from 'html-to-image';
```

Then set page dimensions for `jsPDF`, then simply use `HtmlToImage` to get Canvas then set width, height and image Canvas with variables then simply add image to `doc` and save it. my functions are same but in first switch case I'll get `PDF`, in second I'll get `JPEG`.

If you're trying to do the first way but get download link in Vue page you must do the controller just like i explained at above then in `VUE` when u do API call you should use BLOB to download the file. Here's the Example :

```
getPDF(type) {
    axios({
        url : '/api/api_name/exportPDF',
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
        .then(res => {

            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = url;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'pdf.pdf');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
        })
},
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Atlas, much appreciated. Will this work for multiple pages too? I'm trying to use Laravel Snappy at the moment. It is a blade template that will be used to convert to PDF.

Comment: @Matt well ofc it will work, but you must realize what's your logic to get result. if you test this and it's worked please mark answer, then with another question explain what you want, and what's your logic, to help you in another topic. there are other ways to but, i tried to explain in this answer most easiest/legit answer you can get with these 3 methods.